# How can I use a radio button on one form to dictate an action on another form?

Tags: c#, date, radio-button, preferences

I have an application where I have a "preferences" form in order to allow the user to select their preferences. The form has some radio buttons that will allow the user to choose their preferences. On another form, I have some code which will react differently depending on which button is checked.

The code/preferences interface is as follows:

[image: The "Preferences" interface.]

```
private void DateStamp()
    {
        if (UserPreferences.Instance.ddmmyyyy.Checked)
        {
            int CaretPosition = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart;
            string TextBefore = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(0, CaretPosition);
            string textAfter = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(CaretPosition);
            string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText = currentDate;
        }
        else if (UserPreferences.Instance.mmddyyyy.Checked)
        {
            int CaretPosition = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart;
            string TextBefore = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(0, CaretPosition);
            string textAfter = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(CaretPosition);
            string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
            richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText = currentDate;
        }
        else if (UserPreferences.Instance.yyyyddmm.Checked)
        {
            int CaretPosition = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart;
            string TextBefore = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(0, CaretPosition);
            string textAfter = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(CaretPosition);
            string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM");
            richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText = currentDate;
        }
        else if (UserPreferences.Instance.yyyymmdd.Checked)
        {
            int CaretPosition = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart;
            string TextBefore = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(0, CaretPosition);
            string textAfter = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(CaretPosition);
            string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText = currentDate;
        }
```

There is no code behind the radio buttons. The modifiers are public.

The issue I have, though is that when I try to add a "Datestamp", I get a System.NullReferenceException {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} error on line "if (UserPreferences.Instance.ddmmyyyy.Checked)". I'm unsure of what to do now.

So what *should* happen when the user goes to add a datestamp, is it should check the checked state of the radio buttons and add the datestamp that corresponds to the checked radio button.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---EDIT---

On the "Preferences" form, the code behind the "Save" button is now as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddmmyyyy.Checked)
            DataFormat = ddmmyyyy.Text;
        else if (mmddyyyy.Checked)
            DataFormat = mmddyyyy.Text;
        else if (yyyyddmm.Checked)
            DataFormat = yyyyddmm.Text;
        else if (yyyymmdd.Checked)
            DataFormat = yyyymmdd.Text;
        //--------------------------------------------------
        if (qwerty.Checked)
            KeyboardFormat = qwerty.Text;
        else if (qwertz.Checked)
            KeyboardFormat = qwertz.Text;
        else if (azerty.Checked)
            KeyboardFormat = azerty.Text;
        else if (dvorak.Checked)
            KeyboardFormat = dvorak.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
```

And the Main Form strings:

```
public partial class Basic_Word_Processor : Form
{
    public string keyboardFormat;
    public string dataFormat;
```

And the MainForm "ShowDialog" code:

```
private void preferencesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserPreferences pref = new UserPreferences();
        pref.ShowDialog();

        dataFormat = pref.DataFormat;
        keyboardFormat = pref.KeyboardFormat;
    }
```

The issue is that it doesn't save the "checked" status of the buttons. It returns to the previous state as soon as the Dialog is closed.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is now that it doesn't keep the button checked. It does work, though. How can I keep it checked?

Comment: Thanks. And I've also got the keyboard part working using your code. Thanks for baring with me today. Hopefully I can get this sorted now with your update. :)

Comment: you're welcome my friend , and please choose the answer below as your Question Answer , It would be really appreciated , I'm really glad that I was able to help you today , good luck :)

Comment: It seems to be working fine now. If anything else happens, I'll inform you through this question. Thank you so much for your help today.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain, but how can I save the check state so when the user reloads the program, it loads up the settings with the program so they haven't got to specify it every time the program loads?

Comment: well , that can't be explained here , but you may consider writing them to a text file and read it when program is starting , just search for Text File Read and write in c# , that's one simple way of doing it

Comment: you're welcome my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by understanding this example you can do what you're attending to do :

I have a main form called `Form1` I want to show User Choices in this form .
and also I added a new form called `Preferences` so user will be able to choose date Format and Keyboard Layout :

my radio buttons are named like this :

```
RB_D_1
RB_D_2
.
.
.
```

after user clicks on `Submit Changes` we'll check which radioButton is selected and store it's `Text` property (ex `RB_D_1.text` is "dd/MM/yyyy" ) to a `Public String Variable` called `DateFormat` here we go :

```
    public string DataFormat, KeyboardFormat;

    private void CMDSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RB_D_1.Checked)
            DataFormat = RB_D_1.Text;
        else if (RB_D_2.Checked)
            DataFormat = RB_D_2.Text;
        else if (RB_D_3.Checked)
            DataFormat = RB_D_3.Text;
        else if (RB_D_4.Checked)
            DataFormat = RB_D_4.Text;
        else
            DataFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"; // default format

        //--------------------------------

        if (RB_L_1.Checked)
            KeyboardFormat = RB_L_1.Text;
        else if (RB_L_2.Checked)
            KeyboardFormat = RB_L_2.Text;
        else if (RB_L_3.Checked)
            KeyboardFormat = RB_L_3.Text;
        else if (RB_L_4.Checked)
            KeyboardFormat = RB_L_4.Text;
        else
            KeyboardFormat = "QWERTY"; // default format


        this.Close();
    }
```

now we have saved user choices in two string variables so we can reach them from our `Form1`

in `Form1` whenever user clicks on `Setting` we'll make an object from our `Preferences` form and Show it to user after closing the Preferences form , we'll check those two string Variables which we already talked about and decide what to do with those results :

for example I stored those results into another two string variables and Showed Them in `TextBoxes`

```
    private void CMDSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // showing the Preferences form to user 
        Preferences pref = new Preferences();
        pref.ShowDialog();

        // getting results from Preferences Form
        dateFormat = pref.DataFormat;
        keyboardFormat = pref.KeyboardFormat;

        // Showing the Result in TextBoxes
        textBox1.Text = dateFormat ;
        textBox2.Text = keyboardFormat;
    }
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

change `DateStamp()` like this :

```
private void DateStamp()
{
    if (dateFormat.ToUpper() == "DD/MM/YYYY")
    {
        int CaretPosition = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart;
        string TextBefore = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(0, CaretPosition);
        string textAfter = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(CaretPosition);
        string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText = currentDate;
    }
    else if (dateFormat.ToUpper() == "MM/DD/YYYY")
    {
        int CaretPosition = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart;
        string TextBefore = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(0, CaretPosition);
        string textAfter = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(CaretPosition);
        string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
        richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText = currentDate;
    }
    else if (dateFormat.ToUpper() == "YYYY/DD/MM")
    {
        int CaretPosition = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart;
        string TextBefore = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(0, CaretPosition);
        string textAfter = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(CaretPosition);
        string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM");
        richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText = currentDate;
    }
    else if (dateFormat.ToUpper() == "YYYY/MM/DD")
    {
        int CaretPosition = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart;
        string TextBefore = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(0, CaretPosition);
        string textAfter = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(CaretPosition);
        string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText = currentDate;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 3 :**

for remembering user choices do this :

add this function to `Preferences`

```
    public void UpdateUserChoice(string date,string keyboard)
    {
        if (date == RB_D_1.Text)
            RB_D_1.Checked = true;
        else if (date == RB_D_2.Text)
            RB_D_2.Checked = true;
        else if (date == RB_D_3.Text)
            RB_D_3.Checked = true;
        else if (date == RB_D_4.Text)
            RB_D_4.Checked = true; 

        //---------------------------

        if (keyboard == RB_L_1.Text)
            RB_L_1.Checked = true;
        else if (keyboard == RB_L_2.Text)
            RB_L_2.Checked = true;
        else if (keyboard == RB_L_3.Text)
            RB_L_3.Checked = true;
        else if (keyboard == RB_L_4.Text)
            RB_L_4.Checked = true; 
    }
```

and change the old way of showing to user like this :

```
    private void CMDSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences pref = new Preferences();
        pref.UpdateUserChoice(dateFormat, keyboardFormat);
        pref.ShowDialog();
        dateFormat = pref.DataFormat;
        keyboardFormat = pref.KeyboardFormat;
        textBox2.Text = keyboardFormat;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. I should have mentioned, though that the "Preferences" form is separate to the main form. The code displayed here is on the main form and is run when a button is clicked. The preferences are on a separate form.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question well but I added the first block of code in the `prefForm` and the second block to the button which user clicks on the `mainForm` so after showing the `prefform` to user we can understand what options have been chosen by user and use them in `mainForm` , isn't it what you're looking for ?

Comment: I'll try and explain a bit clearer (Sorry, I've only recently started programming). I have a form (which is pictured above) which has preference options. On my main form, there is a "datestamp" option which when the user clicks the button, it inputs the date to the rtb. The radio buttons *should* control which format the date is in (as shown in the code), but I get the error ystem.NullReferenceException {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} error on line "if (UserPreferences.Instance.ddmmyyyy.Checked)". I need to overcome the error so that it works as expected.

Comment: I'm going to have it so that the user checks the button and it saves the preference, so even if they close and open the form, the check stays the same. I'm going to work on saving the check status as soon as I have this part working first.

Comment: no problem , wait a minute I'll add a project here then you can check if it's working fine for you or not.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that's the kind of thing I wish to achieve. I will take a look at the code and try and implement it into my program and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I just need to figure out how I can use the current code with your code.. I'm new to programming (as I said before), so trying to do that isn't easy for me... So please bare with me. :-)

Comment: I'll help you as much as I can , and Don't worry these kind of efforts are really helpful for your programming , take as much time as you need , just don't give up on it :)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, if you could give me a hand to figure this out, I'd really appreciate it. :)

Comment: you're welcome , Answer is updated , chick it out , let me know if It solves the problem

Comment: The only thing I'm really confused about the DataFormat = ddmmyyyy.Text; part... I'm confused how I make this correspond with what I'm trying to do... Could you perhaps help me please? :)

Comment: I added that line because we need Default setting for our program maybe user doesn't want to choose date format so we make sure we have a default format ourselves but that's not really important you can ignore it , just think about the whole concept

Comment: and look , you can also use `dateFormat = "radio 1"` , or anything else , we just want to know what radio is selected , do it in any way you like , and then use that in the `mainform` , so what do you think ?

Comment: :) what should I say ?! now you should decide what you want to do whit user choices , you have saved them , now you can use them to do anything , It's totally up to you , my friend

Comment: please visit http://codeproject.com time to time it's a wonderful website for c# developers and one last thing , Code is poetry , enjoy it ;)

Comment: if this answer helped you out you may also consider choosing it as your question answer , thanks

Comment: One other question. Does the first block of code you supplied go on the "Preferences" form and the second block go on the Main form?

Comment: yes and both of them are for two different buttons ! first for `CMDSubmit` in `Preferences` and second one for `CMDSettings` in `Form1`

Comment: I'm going to edit the question to show the current code. Sorry I'm quite slow at this coding stuff.